# HTML Element - Does "value" attribute or property exist?

Tags: javascript, dom

How can you determine if an html element has a "value" property/attribute?

**Textarea example:**

```
let textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
textarea.innerHTML = "Sike!"; 
console.log(textarea.hasAttribute("value")); // returns false (expected true)
console.log(textarea.hasOwnProperty("value")); // returns false (expected true)
console.log(textarea.value); // returns "Sike!";
```

**Div Example:**

```
let div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = "Sike!"; 
console.log(div.hasAttribute("value")); // returns false (expected false)
console.log(div.hasOwnProperty("value")); // returns false (expected false)
console.log(div.value); // returns undefined; (expected thrown error)
```

Comment: @bsplosion I don't think that question has anything to really do with this one.

Comment: Is it an input, select, button, or textarea? it has a value! the possible tag names are small enough that being able to determine in other ways is simply not necessary.

Comment: @LonnieBest i mean, not necessarily. Several of those answers have things that work in your case.

Comment: But `in` works with the prototype chain. Try it `let a = {val: 42}; let b = Object.create(a); console.log('val' in b);`

Comment: Looks like `.value` is a getter property that is inherited from the prototype of the textarea element object. But really this should not matter anywhere. What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

Comment: console.log(("value" in elementVariableName));   works. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could test if a property named `'value'` exists in the (non-standard) `__proto__` property of your element:

```js
let textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
console.log('value' in textarea.__proto__);
console.log('foo' in textarea.__proto__);
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to test `__proto__` - doing `value in textarea` should work fine and check the prototype chain already. If it didn't work, then `__proto__` wouldn't work either, because the property could be coming from the prototype's prototype, which would require a recursive check of all prototypes.

Comment: Don't use `__proto__` any more, not in code, explanations, or SO answers! It's deprecated by `Object.getPrototypeOf`.